# tsc errors for react-bootstrap in spfx project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, react-bootstrap, spfx

I've scaffolded an SPFX Project using Yeoman generator and added react-bootstrap as a dependency.

Whenever I use any of the react-bootstrap component and gulp serve it, I get the below errors. Has anyone got clue on how to resolve this? Thanks.

```
**Starting subtask 'tslint'...
[13:10:02] [tslint] tslint version: 5.12.1
[13:10:02] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[13:10:02] [tsc] typescript version: 3.7.7
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.d.ts(1,28): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.d.ts(1,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/applyStyles.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/applyStyles.d.ts(1,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/arrow.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/arrow.d.ts(1,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/arrow.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/arrow.d.ts(2,32): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/computeStyles.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/computeStyles.d.ts(1,67): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/eventListeners.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/eventListeners.d.ts(1,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/flip.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/flip.d.ts(1,56): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/flip.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/flip.d.ts(2,40): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/hide.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/hide.d.ts(1,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/offset.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/offset.d.ts(1,32): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/offset.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/offset.d.ts(2,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/popperOffsets.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/popperOffsets.d.ts(1,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/preventOverflow.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/preventOverflow.d.ts(1,56): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/preventOverflow.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/preventOverflow.d.ts(2,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(1,48): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(2,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(3,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(3,35): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(4,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(4,35): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(5,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(5,37): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(6,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(6,45): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(7,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(8,36): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(9,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(9,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(10,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(10,42): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/utils/detectOverflow.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/utils/detectOverflow.d.ts(1,49): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/utils/detectOverflow.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/utils/detectOverflow.d.ts(2,65): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[13:10:11] Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after 9.02 s 
 exited with code 2**
```

Answer (score 3):

The current release of @microsoft/generator-sharepoint defaults to TypeScript 3.7. This causes build breaks when customers use libraries that have been written on newer releases. Please update the default installed compiler to 3.9 or greater.

Fluent UI has a minimum requirement of TS 3.9 (published May 2020.) When using language features in TS 3.9, they cause issues with customers on older releases. Subsequently customers using the yeoman template to generate a webpart will hit TypeScript issues using libraries like Fluent UI.

Customers can work around this by replacing @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.7 with @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9.

Please run following cmdlet

```
 npm uninstall -D @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.7
 npm install -D @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9
```

and update tsconfig